# Show all hours even when no data

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join, recursive-query

I am looking to write a query that shows all hours even when no data is present. I have seen some posts where the suggestion is to create a temporary table that has all the hours listed but I am not sure how to do that. Here is my current query:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(t_stamp, "%h %p") as Hour, count(*) as Count
from cyclehistory
where DATE(t_stamp) = CURRENT_DATE()
group by hour(t_stamp)
```

This works returns the following

```
 Hour | Count
09 AM | 6
10 AM | 11
1 PM  | 5
```

But I would like it to return

```
 Hour | Count
.
.
.
09 AM | 6
10 AM | 11
11 AM | 0
12 PM | 0
1 PM  | 5
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You do need *some kind* of table of numbers to do this. Here, you just need 24 numbers, from 0 to 23. Say the numbers table is called `numbers` with column `num`:

```
select maketime(n.num, 0, 0) as t_time, count(c.t_stamp) cnt
from numbers n
left join cyclehistory c 
    on hour(c.tstamp) = n.num
    and c.t_stamp >= current_date and c.t_stamp < current_date + interval 1 day
group by n.num
```

There are multiple ways to build the number table. You can create a table and insert records manually:

```
create table numbers (num int primary key);
insert into numbers values (0), (1), ..., (23);
```

For a one-time task, you can create a derived table directly in the query:

```
select ...
from (
    select 0 num
    union all select 1
    ...
    union all select 23
) numbers
left join ...
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query:

```
with recursive numbers (num) as (
    select 0
    union all select num + 1 from cte where num < 23
)
select ...
from numbers 
left join ...
```

Comment: That worked thank you! Another question, how would I have it order it by the time and is it possible to format it to 9 AM, 10 AM, ect.